# Jenkins 2.19.3 compatibility with Nexus 3.18

Tags: jenkins, nexus

My Jenkins current version is 2.19.3 with Java 7, and I am planning to upgrade my NXRM to 3.18 which will use JAVA 8, so does my Nexus upgrade impact Jenkins and Sonar running on Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins and Sonar work with java8 with no problems.

Comment: If I am clear, you mean that Jenkins running in java 7 is compatible with nexus running in java 8, right?

Answer (score 0):

Every one of the apps you list starts up its own jvm; they are all independent. As long as you launch the right jvm you are fine. It worries me that as a developer, you'd be asking this.

Since 2.60, Jenkins has required Java 8 jvm to run. As Jenkins 2.164, it supports running on Java 11 jvm.

Since SonarQube, LTS 6.x, I believe, it has required Java 8 jvm to run. As of LTS 7.9, Java 11 jvm is required. It will still anaylze java 8 code.

Evidently, you should really be upgrading your SonarQube and especially Jenkins instances well. Jenkins in particular  has had many security improvements.

Comment: Got your point. Will look forward to upgrade my Jenkins and sonar as well. Thanks!!